# Prove that symmetric difference is distributive across intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been studying sets, relations and groups and I came across this question. Somehow I can not answer it. I hope I understand correctly, if symmetric difference is distributive over intersection then:

A Δ (B ∩ C) = (A Δ B) ∩ (A Δ C)

I also realise that:

A Δ B = (A\B) ∪ (B\A)

however I get stuck quickly when trying to prove it using this. I have searched for answers but the only proof I can find is the proof that intersection is distributive over symmetric difference.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using boolean algebra, $a  \triangle b = 1$ if their values are different and $0$ otherwise. On the set $\{1,1,0\}$ we have on the left side $1 \triangle (1*0) = 1 \triangle 0 = 1$, but on the right side $(1\triangle 1) * (1\triangle 0) = 0*1 = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

I think you argument is incorrect. For that, consider the following counter example:

Let  $A=\{ 1,2,3,4\}$,  $B=\{1,3,5,7 \}$,  and  $C=\{1,2,4,6 \}$.

Then $$B \cap C= \{ 1\}$$
and  $$ A \Delta (B\cap C) = \{ 2,3,4\}$$
However $$ (A \Delta B) \cap (A \Delta C)= \{2,4,5,7 \} \cap \{ 3,6\} = \phi  \color{red}{\neq }\{ 2,3,4\} =A \Delta (B\cap C) $$

Comment: Maybe the question in your text book should be  the inverse : show that intersection is distributive over symmetric difference !

Comment: Wow I had not realised that, but I am still not sure where I made the error, my textbook says that an operation * is distributive over another operation º when: 
A * (B º C) = (A * B) º (A * C)

is then the claim that symmetric difference is distributive over set intersection simply wrong? 

And I do apologize if this question is very basic, I just got really confused.

Comment: I think that just might be the case as I came across similar errors in this textbook before.